# Mongodb - Empty _id in collection when inserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb

With high hopes that someone can help me, here is what I am facing.

I have a collection with no documents : collection name : calendar_event

The mongodb server is running in replicaset mode with two nodes (Primary and secondary).

When I try to create a new document using Nodejs Driver 2.0 with options to forceServerObjectId set to true, I see the _id as empty string.

MongoDB Conf :

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://' + url, {
            db: {
                w: 1,
                forceServerObjectId: true
            },
            replSet: {
                replicaSet:'obtors0'
            }
        },
        self.openConnection(source) // Connection callback
    );
```

NodeJS:

```
db_collection.insertOne(data, function (error, result) {

                        //id = result.insertedId;

                        if (self.app !== null) {

                            self._finalizeCreate(tableName, error, result,
                                _callback);
                            //id = result.insertedId;

                        } else {
                            _callback(null, result);
                        }


                        callback(null, 3);

                    });
```

Now one could argue this could be Nodejs Issue so for that I have other collections in which I don't see this problem at all. Its just this one collection.

I tried the following but nothing has helped :

1. Restart the mongodb server
2. Make sure I have the latest/stable nodejs driver
3. Restarted my node app several times
4. Removed all indexes from the collection
5. Dropped and recreated the collection

Appreciate anyone helping.

Cheers
Divy

Comment: Hi. Just to be sure, you are talking about top-level mongo collections? Not some sub-collection? Because only mongo collection gets _id generated automaticaly. If you save any document with embeded collection (or document), no _id for it will be generated.

Comment: What happens if you try without forceServerObjectId, does it work then?  Any specific reason for forcing the server to create the identity?

Comment: @MartinBrabec  - It's a top level collection.

Comment: @jdarling - I tried without forceServerObjectId , still the same problem. Its just this one collection. Every other collection seems to work fine.

Comment: For now, I am explicitly adding a new ObjectId to the data before inserting it into the DB.

Thanks @jdarling for your comment.